# Ubuntu live cd wont boot from OLD machine

Tags: live-cd, windows-vista

i trying to install ubuntu 12.04.3 on a (not super old) old laptop. When i boot from the cd it just displays a black screen with a _ blinking at the top. I have installed ubuntu before but this has never happened. After that it boots into windows vista :( Its a TOSHIBA with 1gb ram but i dont know more about the computer as i got it only to replace windows with ubuntu. Help will be appreciated! :) Update: I checked the md5sum and its correct.
Update 2:Problem (half) solved! I used a usb and it worked but ill keep what is here for reference if anyone needs it! :)

Comment: Are you trying to boot a 64 bit version of ubuntu on a 32 bit cpu? Might be worth double checking and re-downloading the 32 bit ISO.

Comment: Oh im using the 32 bit one :3 I double checked too

Comment: Try using a different liveCD or LiveUSB, perhaps Lubuntu or Damn Small Linux.

Comment: I cant because i need a VERY simple os because my grandma is going to use this computer T_T

Comment: great that the usb did work! I hope your grandma will enjoy ubuntu ^^

Answer (score 0):

you can [check the md5 sum of the iso](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) you burned to make sure your download is not corrupted. you can also put the cd in an other computer to see if the problem is specific for this computer.

Comment: The disc is probaly not broken as it shows its files from windows (wubi.exe, and that kind of stuff) but i dont have another computer to try on, Is there any other solution than that?

Comment: do you have a running pc where you can put the cd in? and what os does it run? in the link in my post there is also something about checking the cd. it is a bit to complicated to add it all to this answer. If you are on Ubuntu and you just want to check the files on the cd you can run `cd /media/cdrom` and than `md5sum -c md5sum.txt | grep -v "OK$"` you can also check the whole disc but that is more complicated and is described in the linked page

Comment: well i only have a mac (posting this stuff on) and a pc (the on im going to install linux on) so i dunno

Comment: ok, I am not familiar with macs so I cannot help you very much with it, in the same article there is something about checking md5 sums on mac otherwise you could try to download a new image and burn it on a new cd and see if that works better. It might not be the issue but a faulty download or disc is very easy to resolve so I always make sure this is not the problem before digging deeper.

Comment: what article are you even talking about :P (link me it)

Comment: I linked the text "check the md5 sum of the iso" in my answer but here is the link: [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)

Comment: well the md5sum is correct